# How to get data from a SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences

I need to use sessions into my application so, I created a java class called `SessionManager` and here I initialized my sessions but when I created three different *get functions* and I use them, the values of the sessions has been overwritten...

My funtions are:

```
public String getBname() {
    return pref.getString(BREAKFAST_NAME,null);
}

public String getBcalories() {
    return pref.getString(BREAKFAST_CALORIES,null);
}

public String getBquantity() {
    return pref.getString(BREAKFAST_QUANTITY,null);
}
```

and I call them in this way:

```
 String name=sessionDay.getBname();
 String calories=sessionDay.getBcalories();
 String quantity=sessionDay.getBquantity();
 etFBreakFast.setText("Name: " + name + "\n" + "Calories: " + calories + "\n" + "Quantity: " + quantity);
```

So what is the problem?

Comment: You should read the Shared Preferences section of this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) in order to save, retrieve or delete. Check out the following code.

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = null;
public static void storeToPrefs(Context context, String key, String value) {
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key,value);
    editor.commit();
}


public static String retrieveFromPrefs(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    try {
        return prefs.getString(key, defaultValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

public static void deleteAllPrefs(Context context){
    prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    prefs.edit().clear().commit();
}
```